# When I create a table in docxtbl, the right line of the last column of the table does not appear

Tags: python, docxtpl

```
class EventGenerateAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = ALL_PERMISSIONS

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        event_id = self.kwargs.get("event_id")
        queryset = Event_Management.objects.filter(id=event_id)
        if user.role.code == RoleCodes.ADMIN:
            return queryset
        elif user.role.code in [
            RoleCodes.IIB_ADMIN,
            RoleCodes.MG_ADMIN,
            RoleCodes.FVV_ADMIN,
        ]:
            return queryset.filter(responsible_to_event__user=user)
        else:
            return queryset.filter(created_by=user)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if not queryset.exists():
            return Response(
                {"error": "Event not found"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
            )

        event = queryset.first()
        mg_armed_force_exists = Responsible.objects.filter(
            event_management=event, armed_force__short_name_uz=AgencyCodes.MG
        ).exists()
        allocated_technical_means = Allocated_Technical_Means.objects.filter(
            event_management=event
        )
        service_types = Service_Type.objects.all().order_by("id")
        iib_numbers = get_allocated_technical_means_numbers(
            allocated_technical_means, AgencyCodes.IIB, service_types
        )
        mg_numbers = get_allocated_technical_means_numbers(
            allocated_technical_means, AgencyCodes.MG, service_types
        )
        fvv_numbers = get_allocated_technical_means_numbers(
            allocated_technical_means, AgencyCodes.FVV, service_types
        )
        template_path = "apps/event/fixtures/event_3.docx"
        doc = DocxTemplate(template_path)

        context = {
            "responsible": event.responsible,
            "document_name": event.document_name,
            "date": f"{event.date.day}.{event.date.month}.{event.date.year}",
            "time": event.time,
            "event_object_name": event.event_object_name,
            "number_of_citizens": event.number_of_citizens,
            "instruction_time": event.instruction_time,
            "mg_armed_force_exists": mg_armed_force_exists,
            "col_labels": service_types.values_list("name_cyr", flat=True),
            "tbl_contents": [
                {
                    "label": "ИИВ",
                    "cols": [iib_numbers[i] for i in range(10)],
                },
                {
                    "label": "ФВВ",
                    "cols": [fvv_numbers[i] for i in range(10)],
                },
                {"label": "Жами", "cols": total_number(iib_numbers, fvv_numbers)},
            ],
            "f_tbl_contents": [
                {
                    "label": "ИИВ",
                    "cols": [iib_numbers[i] for i in range(10)],
                },
                {
                    "label": "МГ",
                    "cols": [mg_numbers[i] for i in range(10)],
                },
                {
                    "label": "ФВВ",
                    "cols": [fvv_numbers[i] for i in range(10)],
                },
                {
                    "label": "Жами",
                    "cols": total_number(iib_numbers, fvv_numbers, mg_numbers),
                },
            ],
        }
        doc.render(context)

        # Convert DOCX to PDF
        pdf_buffer = BytesIO()
        temp_docx_path = "/tmp/temp_docx.docx"

        # Save the rendered DOCX content to a temporary file
        doc.save(temp_docx_path)

        # Use LibreOffice to convert DOCX to PDF
        libreoffice_command = [
            "libreoffice",
            "--headless",
            "--convert-to",
            "pdf",
            "--outdir",
            "/tmp",
            temp_docx_path,
        ]

        try:
            subprocess.run(libreoffice_command, check=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            # Handle the conversion error as needed
            raise Exception(f"LibreOffice conversion error: {e}")

        # Read the generated PDF file
        with open("/tmp/temp_docx.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file:
            pdf_buffer = BytesIO(pdf_file.read())

        # Prepare the response with the PDF content
        response = HttpResponse(pdf_buffer, content_type="application/pdf")
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="event_3.pdf"'
        return response
```

in docx
| Хизмат номи      | {%tc for col in col_labels%} | {{ col }} | {%tc endfor%} |
|-------------------------------------------------|---------------------------|
|{%tr for item in f_tbl_contents %}                                           |
|------------------|------------------------------|---------------------------|
| {{ item.label }} | {%tc for col in item.cols %} | {{ col }} | {%tc endfor %}|
|------------------|------------------------------|---------------------------|
| {%tr endfor %}                                                              |

in pdf

| Хизмат | one | two | three | other
|  номи  |     |     |       |
|--------|-----|-----|-------|-------
| ASD    | 112 | 321 |  411  |  500
|--------|-----|-----|-------|-------
| MG     |  1  |  2  |   3   |   5
|--------|-----|-----|-------|-------
| Total  | 113 | 323 |  414  |  505